# i need to create a .net 4.0 deployment setup in french language

Tags: c#, .net, prerequisites

I am working in .net 4.0, I need to create deployment setup in visual studio 2012 with all prerequisites like .netframework 4.0,sqlite etc.

when i create the setup in english (default), it is working good, means it is installing all the things properly on client machine.
But when i change the default language to french, it give an error

> 1: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64fr.exe' in item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
>
> 2: General failure building bootstrapper
>
> 3: Unrecoverable build error

Please help me, how can i remove this error.

Another thing is that when i change the settings for prerequisites like "download the prerequisites from the vendor's website", then it does not give an error.
But i need to install from local disk/folder including in setup folder.

Comment: Do you really have the French install of Dotnet in your local folder ?

Comment: i dont know, how can i install.My client's system is in french and he need the setup in french.During creation of deployment setup, there is an option for french but build is not created successfully.
I downloaded the file dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64fr.exe and placed it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40 but not working. same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to **place the file into the proper language directory**.

Here, you're missing the `\fr` part in your path.

So you must place the file `dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64fr.exe` to directory `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40\fr` for 64 bit windows or to `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40\fr` for 32 bit windows.